# How to connect Jwt protected Express.js Rest api with angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, express, jwt

I protected my api with json web token. How can I connect this to my angular app. There will be no Login and Register in the application.

I've done a lot of research on Google, youtube and stackoverflow. But I never found the result I wanted.

I just want to show the data to the people who enter the website. I don't want anyone outside the website to access the Json file.

Here is my express.js

```
const app = require('express')()
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const fs = require('fs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const PORT = 3002

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({message: 'Api'})
  })

  app.post('/api/login',(req, res)=> {
    const user = { id: 3 }
    const token = jwt.sign({ user }, 'our_key')
    res.json({
      token: token
    })
  })

  app.get('/api/protected', ensureToken,(req, res)=>  {
    jwt.verify(req.token, 'our_key',function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(403)
      } else {
        fs.readFile('data.json','utf-8',(err,data)=>{
          res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;     charset=utf-8")
          data = JSON.parse(data)
          console.log(data)
          res.end(JSON.stringify(data,null,4))
      })
      }
    })
  })

  function ensureToken(req, res, next) {
    const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"]
    if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
      const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ")
      const bearerToken = bearer[1]
      req.token = bearerToken
      next()
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(403)
    }
  }

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('Server http://localhost:'+ PORT + ' OK')  
  })
```

Wherever angular and jwt are connected via Login / Register system. Can we do it without this?

Comment: What you can do is in my opinion an absolut anti-security pattern. You could generate a long life token manually and pass this stored token along the http requests with an interceptor. 

But you should consider some security mechanism to authenticate a user. Maybe you should explain in more depth which is the purpose of the whole thing to get an closer solution to your particular problem.

Comment: @MarcHägele I edited my question. I just want something simple.

Comment: you can add token to your request using https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor it intercepts all outgoing requests and can modify them however you wish and if you want something simple just but unsecure you can add token there but without authentication someone can take that token and use it outside of your page

Answer (score 0):

In this case the only solution I see is the following (and its not 100% secure to be honest)

the first thing you should do on backend side is:

```
app.use(cors({
     origin: 'http://yourapp.com'
}));
```

to restrict cors to other domains.

Second part on the angular side is to get an token to work and to communicate with the backend on the interceptor side.

After reviewing the Code it should look like the following:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Stackoverflow - Test</title>
    <base href="/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

appModule.ts

```html
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './data.service';
import { RouterModule, ROUTES } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [ {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: TokenInterceptor,
    multi: true,
}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './data.model';
import { Value } from './data.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

 users:User[];
 
 constructor(private _http: HttpClient){}

 ngOnInit(){
   this.loadData();
 }

  public async getToken(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('try to get token from api');
    const result: any = await this._http
              .get(`http://localhost:3002/api/login`)
              .toPromise();

    localStorage.setItem('userToken', result.token);
  }

 private async loadData(): Promise<void> {
   if (localStorage.getItem('userToken') == null) {
      await this.getToken();
   }
  
    const result = await this._http.get(`http://localhost:3002/api/protected`)
                .toPromise();

    console.log(result);
 }
}
```

and your data.service.ts  (which normally for this purpose should be named token.interceptor.ts or something like this.

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './data.model';
import {map, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
  intercept(
      request: HttpRequest<any>,
      next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      let currentToken =
          localStorage.getItem('userToken') ||
          sessionStorage.getItem('userToken');
        const authReq = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + currentToken || []
            }
        });
        return next.handle(authReq);
}
}
```

Comment: I've edited the code locally, but I couldn't run it. I uploaded edited version to StackBlitz. Of course it won't work because it's localhost, but I couldn't find out where I made a mistake. Can u check? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwt-try

Comment: Will check tomorrow morning. At first look what I saw is on appmodule you are injecting routes which are not present in code (came from the pseudo sample.) and later to call the get method from _http service in the component the _http client have to be injected in constructor with: private _http: HttpClient

Comment: have modified the response to fix a mistake. Should work for your needs.